# Split a Django Queryset into subquerysets

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models

I have a model with around 4 million objects.

I would like to write a function which can split the all objects of a queryset into sub querysets of length 100000 objects.

e.g.

```
all_objects = MyModel.objects.all()

# do the splitting to achieve something like below 
query_set1 = all_objects[0:100000]
query_set2 = all_objects[100000:200000]
# and so on until all objects are within 
query_setn = all_objects[3 900 000:4 000 000]
```

Comment: Why? What is the use case?

Comment: I am trying to delete all of the data in the model, but the MySQL server limits Django .delete() and raw_detelete(). Unfortunately, I can't change MySQL server settings to allow the delete functions to work. So my tactic was to split the objects into subqueries and delete them one by one.

Comment: problem is that if you delete the first queryset, the items will "move" to the front.

Answer (score 0):

If processing the queryset in one burst will not fit into memory, you can use the [**`.iterator(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#iterator) to make this a queryset that will load chunks in memory. The advantage is, you still can enumerate one item at a time, and thus most of the API is just like a normal queryset.

You thus can work with:

```
for item in MyModel.objects.iterator(chunk_size=100_000):
    # …
    pass
```

If you want to remove all items in a query, you can work with:

```
to_delete = True
while to_delete:
    to_delete, __ = MyModel.objects.filter(
        pk__in=[item.pk for item in MyModel.objects.only('pk')[:100_000]]
    ).delete()
```

This is not massively efficient, but a lot better than enumerating each item one-by-one.

We here each time check if we removed anything, and if so, perform another run.

Note that if `ForeignKey`s link to `MyModel` deleting even a single `MyModel` record can result in remove millions of records in other tables. So while we slice the `MyModel`, that does not say much about removing other model objects.

Comment: @ItIsMeYa: there was a small typo, that is now updated.